# Как правильно включить pre-render к связке Laravel+VueJS?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js, seo

У меня есть приложение, написанное на Laravel, в связке с VueJS, в котором подключены VueRouter и VueAxios. Проблема заключается в том, что сайт не может сканироваться поисковыми роботами. Для этого я решил организовать pre-render нужных мне страниц. Пробовал подключать к приложению плагин Prerender-SPA-Plugin в связке с Html-Webpack-Plugin. Есть один мануал в сети, но там экспериментировали с Laravel 5.4 (у меня 5.6).

Исходники: https://github.com/msdnna/37computer-ambulance

Важные компоненты:

app.js: https://pastebin.com/JpxnKa8j

servicespage.vue: https://pastebin.com/g0TLA9ei

vueapp.blade.php: https://pastebin.com/ptgFRzsr

web.php (routes): https://pastebin.com/b9dAD8RW

webpack.config.js: https://pastebin.com/YDs7tE5X

Comment: для prerender этого плагина по идее без разницы какой у вас ларавель, там же настраивать все на фронтенде надо

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы использовать Vue Prerender, можно использовать [этот](https://github.com/snipcart/vue-seo-prerender) плагин.
Там есть подробная инструкция внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проще будет использовать готовую сборку с серверным рендерингом - https://ru.nuxtjs.org/. Там и router, и axios, и server-render, и всё это на vue в готовой сборке